# Power BI categorical data count in a bar chart

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, categorical-data

I'm having the Power BI desktop version on my laptop. My dataset consists of a number of categorical data. I need to get the pie chart and the bar chart of the categories against the count. Is there any specific way to do it. We can plot the categorical variable against another numerical value. But not seems like against its own count.

Kindly inform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to visual how many times a category appears, against that category.

In Power BI, you can bring in a field more than once into a visualisation and perform different actions on it. I would usually put everything into formulas, but you can use the drop and drag interface too.

[Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPKhG.png)

1. Drag the category field into the shared axis
2. Drag it into the Column Value to get a count
3. I dragged category into line values as well to show the %. Right click on the count, then go down to the option "show value as" and select % of grand total.

Comment: Thanks Ronan, Do you know any good resources to learn formulas. I too tried a formula approach and it worked. But I need to learn more.

Comment: The two beginner courses at enterprise dna are free, which can teach you the basics, as well as give you example .pbix files